# Find the name and the average IMDb rating of those movie-genres whose average IMDb rating is greater than or equal to 7.5 in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `movie` table inside my `Movie_Info` database which contains `Movie_Name`, `Movie_I`D, `IMDB_Rating`, `Genre` etc fields. Like this:

[image]

Now I need to **find the name(name of genre) and the average IMDb rating of those movie-genres whose average IMDb rating is greater than or equal to 7.5.**

my approach is:

```
SELECT
        Genre
        ,AVG (IMDB_Rating) AS AVG_IMDB_Rating
    FROM
        movie
    WHERE
        AVG (IMDB_Rating) >= 7.5
;
```

But it gives error. Please help me to write the proper SQL.

Comment: How about showing error ?

Comment: You need `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group by for this purpose along with having clause.

```
SELECT
    Genre
    ,AVG (IMDB_Rating) AS AVG_IMDB_Rating
FROM
    movie
group by Genre
having AVG (IMDB_Rating) >= 7.5
```